# Standardized estimates give different p-value with a glmer/lmer

Tags: r, standardization, lme4-nlme

I have a large data set where I relate the response variable to multiple explanatory variables; since I have different areas I have also included a random factor. 
The response variable is binomial and therefore I use the `glmer` function from the `lme4` package. 
The explanatory variables have different scales and to be able to compare the estimates I wanted to standardize the estimates. 
For that I use a [standardisation method](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/unpublished/standardizing.pdf) that has been developed by Gelman (2007), which is available in the `arm` package. 
Another method would be fine as well, however I use this for a different model, and I would like to use the same method to standardize my data.

However if I use this method, I get different $p$-values:

```
# without standardized data: 
model1 <- glmer(bembryo ~ (s_edlength + s_bplength + s_tide)^2 + (1|Areasite), family=binomial(link = "logit"), nAGQ = 1, data=data)

Fixed effects:
                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)           -1.81791    2.86350  -0.635   0.5255  
s_edlength            12.33513    5.52290   2.233   0.0255 *
s_bplength            -8.77016    4.74700  -1.847   0.0647 .
s_tide                 1.54429    1.38453   1.115   0.2647  
s_edlength:s_bplength -0.01579    0.14525  -0.109   0.9134  
s_edlength:s_tide     -4.77805    2.23256  -2.140   0.0323 *
s_bplength:s_tide      3.47744    1.89254   1.837   0.0661 .   

# With standardized data: 

model.full.stan <- standardize(model1)

Fixed effects:
                          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                 3.1441     0.7192   4.372 1.23e-05 ***
z.s_edlength                5.9579     2.4137   2.468   0.0136 *  
z.s_bplength               -4.0340     2.1221  -1.901   0.0573 .  
z.s_tide                   -1.3594     1.1632  -1.169   0.2425    
z.s_edlength:z.s_bplength  -0.1263     1.2467  -0.101   0.9193    
z.s_edlength:z.s_tide     -10.4140     4.9042  -2.123   0.0337 *  
z.s_bplength:z.s_tide       7.9670     4.3625   1.826   0.0678 .
```

I am not really sure why this is happening. 
I checked if it depends on the standardization method I use.
However, if I just use the function `rescale` to scale my explanatory variables I also get different $p$-values. 
I do not get different $p$-values when there is only one explanatory variables left, however that is not really helpful.

This same problem occurs when I use a `lme` function from the `nlme` package. 
Although for this function the method of Gelman (2007) is not possible, I also get different $p$-values compared to the non-standardized model.

I am not sure why this is happening and I really would like to use standardized estimates, so I would hope that someone has a idea why this is happening.

Comment: Rather than using the `standardise` function, which doesn't work on all the estimation functions, what happens if you rescale the input variables manually? So just dividing each input by twice its standard deviation. Does the problem persist?

Comment: I also manually rescale the input variables, this gave the same problem.

Comment: oops, I'm being a dummy.   Since you have interactions in your model, standardizing *will* change the results.

Comment: Oh that I did not know, why does this happen? I don't suppose that there is a solution for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phenomenon you're seeing is not specific to `glmer` or mixed models.  It is a consequence of (1) *centering* as well as scaling your input variables; (2) including interactions in your model.  If you only scale, and don't center your variables (e.g. by using `scale(.,center=FALSE)`), **or** if you drop the interactions from the model, then you should see the magnitudes of your coefficients change, but the $Z$-statistics and $p$-values should remain identical. If you didn't have interactions in the model, then your estimated slopes would represent the *marginal* change in the response per unit of the predictor; because you have interactions, your estimated slopes are the change in the response per unit of the predictor *at the zero value of the other variables included in the interaction*; this makes the estimates sensitive to centering the other input variables.

Answer (score 0):

The phenomenon is related to types of tests ("I", "II", "III") or sums of squares. This is commonly discussed within the context of categorical explanatory variables (traditional ANOVA). But I think that cases involving continuous variables are even more important because it is unlogic that Celsius and Fahrenheit give different results.

With only continuous variables, the usual test of a parameter is equivalent to a Type III test. The Type II test takes the hierarchy of model terms into account. The function Anova in the package car has Type II as the default test. This function can take model objects produced be several functions as input.
Anova in car will handle a model with main effects and interactions (as in the question). Then, standardized and unstandardized data will give the same results.

A limitation of Anova in car is that this function cannot see the hierarchy of polynomial terms. Thus, if you have a quadratic term (e.g. I(x^2)), rescaling the data will change the results.

Package ffmanova is mainly meant as a package for multivariate responses, but it also involves a general contribution to ANOVA testing in linear models. The approach to sums of squares (Type II*) is invariant to scale changes also in the case of polynomial terms. 
See https://doi.org/10.1080/02664760701594246
Try to run code below.

```
library(car)
library(ffmanova)

set.seed(123)
z <- 1:9
x <- c(0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 1, 1, 1)
y <- rnorm(9)/10 + x  # y depends strongly on x
z100 <- z + 100  # change of scale (origin)
x100 <- x + 100  # change of scale (origin)

# Ordinary lm and Type III same results
summary(lm(y ~ x * z))
Anova(lm(y ~ x * z), type = 3)

# Type III depends on scale
Anova(lm(y ~ x100 * z100), type = 3)

# Identical results with Type II
Anova(lm(y ~ x * z), type = 2)
Anova(lm(y ~ x100 * z100), type = 2)

# But quadratic terms are problematic
Anova(lm(y ~ x * z + I(x^2) + I(z^2)), type = 2)
Anova(lm(y ~ x100 * z100 + I(x100^2) + I(z100^2)), type = 2)

# It can be handled by ffmanova
ffmanova(y ~ x * z + I(x^2) + I(z^2))
ffmanova(y ~ x100 * z100 + I(x100^2) + I(z100^2))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an interaction in your model, you should scale the product of the interaction. For example: scale(length * tide). Don't scale each predictor separately for the interaction effect. This way you will get the same p statistics.