# Multicollinearity - mean centering does not reduce the confidence interval of interaction terms?

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction, multicollinearity, standardization

I generated synthetic high-collinearity 10,000 datasets (each of sample size 1,000) using high-covariance matrix with multivariate normal distribution. I fitted 10,000 different linear models and stored their parameter values of the following linear model:

$$y = \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_3 x_3 + \beta_4 x_4 + \beta_5 x_1^2  + \beta_6 x_2 x_3$$

I made boxplots of each parameter values for both the original & standardized data (I standardized data before adding interaction terms)

To my understanding, mean-centering helps with multicollinearity when there are interaction terms. Which mean that it should reduce the confidence interval of the regression coefficients of $A$ and $B$ terms, AND $A \times B$ interaction terms.

But it seems that mean-centering does not reduce the confidence interval of the regression coefficient of $A \times B$ interaction terms, even if I observed significant reduction in VIF after centering.

Does this result agree with the theory, or am I making a mistake in my code?

[image]

Here's the Python source code:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import pandas as pd

def generate_collinear_data(cov, n=10, true_coefs=[0, 0], true_intercept=0, feature_means=[0, 0, 0], loc=0, scale=1):

    # random generation of 3D gaussian collinear features.
    X = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean=feature_means, cov=cov, size=n)

    # generate gaussian white noise.
    gaussian_noise = np.random.normal(loc=loc, scale=scale, size=n)

    # make the outcome.
    y = true_intercept + gaussian_noise
    for i in range(len(true_coefs)):
        y += true_coefs[i] * X[:, i]

    return X, y

# settings
m = 10000                                   # number of simulations
correlation = 0.99                          # degree of collinearity (HIGH)

kwargs = {
    'n': 1000,                              # sample size
    'true_coefs': [13, 0.5, 5, 42],         # linear regression coefficients, 2 features
    'true_intercept': 15,                    # y-intercept
    'feature_means': [-12, 14, 2, -20],     # means multivariate normal distribution. This is not important
    'loc': 0,                               # mean of gaussian noise
    'scale': 1                              # standard deviation of gaussian noise
}

# high collinearity covariance matrix
cov = np.full((len(kwargs['true_coefs']), len(kwargs['true_coefs'])), correlation)
np.fill_diagonal(cov, 1)

# simulation
org_params = []
std_params = []
for i in range(m):

    ################################################ Original ################################################

    # generate high collinearity data
    X_org, y_org = generate_collinear_data(cov, **kwargs)

    # add interaction terms
    interaction_org_1 = X_org[:, 0].reshape(-1, 1) ** 2                            # x1^2
    interaction_org_2 = X_org[:, 1].reshape(-1, 1) * X_org[:, 2].reshape(-1, 1)    # x2 * x3
    X_org = np.concatenate([X_org, interaction_org_1, interaction_org_2], axis=1)

    # VIF
    vifs_org = np.linalg.inv(pd.DataFrame(X_org).corr().values).diagonal()

    # fit linear regression model
    X_st_org = sm.add_constant(X_org)
    model_org = sm.OLS(y_org, X_st_org).fit()
    org_params.append(model_org.params)

    ############################################## Standardized ##############################################

    # generate high collinearity data
    X_std, y_std = generate_collinear_data(cov, **kwargs)

    # standardize
    scaler = StandardScaler(with_std=False)
    X_std, y_std = scaler.fit_transform(X_std), scaler.fit_transform(y_std.reshape(-1, 1)).flatten()

    # add interaction terms
    interaction_std_1 = X_std[:, 0].reshape(-1, 1) ** 2                            # x1^2
    interaction_std_2 = X_std[:, 1].reshape(-1, 1) * X_std[:, 2].reshape(-1, 1)    # x2 * x3
    X_std = np.concatenate([X_std, interaction_std_1, interaction_std_2], axis=1)

    # VIF
    vifs_std = np.linalg.inv(pd.DataFrame(X_std).corr().values).diagonal()    

    # fit linear regression model
    X_st_std = sm.add_constant(X_std)
    model_std = sm.OLS(y_std, X_st_std).fit()
    std_params.append(model_std.params)

    ##########################################################################################################

# list to numpy conversion
org_params = np.asarray(org_params)
std_params = np.asarray(std_params)

# plotting
def styling(ax):
    ax.set_facecolor('#eeeeee')
    ax.grid(True, linestyle='--', color='#acacac')
    ax.tick_params(color='grey')
    _ = [spine.set_edgecolor('grey') for spine in ax.spines.values()]
    #ax.text(0.5, 0.1, 'aegis4048.github.io', fontsize=10.5, ha='center', va='center',
    #        transform=ax.transAxes, color='grey', alpha=0.5)

boxplot_styling = {
    'sym': '',
    'whis': [2.5, 97.5],
    'showfliers': False,
    'vert': True,
    'capprops': dict(linewidth=2.0, color='k'),
    'medianprops': dict(linewidth=2.0, color='k'),
    'widths': (0.4),
    'patch_artist': True,
    'whiskerprops': dict(linewidth=1.5, color='k', linestyle='--'),
}

labels = ['Intercept', '$X_1$', '$X_2$', '$X_3$', '$X_4$', '$X_1^2$', '$X_2X_3$']

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, len(labels), figsize=(16, 6))

for i, (ax, label) in enumerate(zip(axes, labels)):
    bp1 = ax.boxplot(org_params[:, i], positions=[1.0], 
                     boxprops=dict(linewidth=1.5, facecolor='#00bfc4'),
                     **boxplot_styling)
    bp2 = ax.boxplot(std_params[:, i], positions=[1.7], 
                     boxprops=dict(linewidth=1.5, facecolor='#f8766d'),
                     **boxplot_styling)
    styling(ax)
    ax.set_title(label, fontsize=20, y=-0.2)
    if i != 0:
        ax.set_xticklabels(['VIF = {}'.format(int(vifs_org[i - 1])), 
                            'VIF = {}'.format(int(vifs_std[i - 1]))], fontsize=9)
    else:
        ax.set_xticklabels([])

fig.legend([bp1["boxes"][0], bp2["boxes"][0]], ['Original', 'Standardized'], 
           loc='lower center', ncol=3, borderaxespad=0.7, fontsize=17)
fig.suptitle('Effect of standardization for interaction terms - %.f simulations' % m, fontsize=25);
fig.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0.1, 1, 0.9])
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but I don't see where the simulation of the data induces an interaction effect in the actual Y data. I see where it is is calculated for the X data for inclusion in the model. If you don't explicitly imprint an interacting X variables and the resulting Y data you shouldn't see interactions in the model.

Comment: "Should reduce" does not follow: straightforward analysis, as shown at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/443560, indicates the confidence interval ought to remain the same, modulo any floating point roundoff error.

Comment: @whuber are you saying that the confidence interval of "both" the original terms and interaction terms should remain same? If so, what is the point of using mean-centering to reduce the effect of multicollinearity, as it doesn't improve the precision of the estimated coefficients?

Comment: You might be conceiving of "precision" in a different sense than intended.  Mean-centering and rescaling can improve the *numerical precision* associated with limited-precision floating point calculations.  They can do nothing to change the least-squares fit, which remains the same.  Multicollinearity is (confusingly) claimed to "decrease the precision" of the estimates--but that phrase dodges the question "compared to what?" The answer is *if hypothetically you could have had orthogonal, rather than correlated, variables, then their standard errors would have been smaller overall.*